# I have a h1 heading inside my carousel item and i want to fix the position of that heading on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a carousel which contains a heading `agenda-date-heading`. I want that heading to become fixed on scrolling. Right now it doesn't get fixed. The `top` property of css in the class `fixed-position` only changes its position on scroll and not actually fix it. Any suggestions on how to get what I am planning to get here?

```
<div class="container-fluid clearfix" style="padding-left:0; padding-right:0;">
    <div id="left-side" class="agenda-container">
        <div id="agenda-date-container" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active agenda-date" id="dec12">
                    <h1 class="text-center agenda-date-heading">December 12</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item agenda-date" id="dec13">
                    <h1 class="text-center agenda-date-heading">December 13</h1>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#agenda-date-container" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#agenda-date-container" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the css of the what I am trying to implement

```
.fixed-position {
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top:20%;

}

#dec12 {
    background-color: #0081c8;
}

#dec13 {
    background-color: #0b8400;
}

.agenda-date {
    color:white;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin:auto;
}

#agenda-date-container>.carousel-inner>.carousel-item {
    height:40em;
}

.agenda-container {
    width:50%;
    position: relative;
    margin:0;
}

.agenda-date-heading {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    padding-top:50%;
    padding-bottom:20%;
}
```

And this is my jquery

```
var dateOffsetY = $('#agenda-date-container').offset().top;

function dateOffsetScroll(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()>=dateOffsetY) {
        $('.agenda-date-heading').addClass("fixed-position");
    }else {
        $('.agenda-date-heading').removeClass("fixed-position");
    }
}

document.onscroll = dateOffsetScroll;
```

Comment: Your description is not clear whether you want to fix the heading on page scroll or you want to fix the heading on carousel scroll (means when moving to next slide)? It will help if you provide any fiddle

Comment: I want it to be fixed on page scroll